# Ubuntu 20.04 - GNOME DE freezes

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, desktop-environment, troubleshooting

Recently, I installed **Ubuntu 20.04** on my machine with the following specifications:-
Processor: Intel Core i5, **2.30GHz x 4** (four cores)
RAM: 8GB
Graphics Card: AMD Radeon, 4GB

While working on the computer 2 times for long durations (~10 hours), the system froze - only mouse cursor moving, nothing else. Similar situation is described in this answer.

**NOTE:** Both the times, I had only 1 web browser opened (Opera) with just 2-3 tabs. No other heavy application running.

I have been keeping track of CPU usage using the system monitor app, and I have noticed that the CPU cores show unusually* very high usage.
(*When I had Ubuntu 18 installed, it didn't have this problem.)

[image]

What can be the cause of such high CPU usage?
Also, is there a way to throttle CPU usage so it doesn't reach the 100% usage, so as to prevent system freeze?

---

From comments:

when the system froze, I tried to login to the shell using through the command ALT + F1, but instead of shell, login "screen" appeared after some seconds, through which I was able to log into my user profile entering my password. I use the default GNOME desktop enviornment; Originally, I clean-installed Ubuntu via minimal installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start with your quote:

> the system froze - only mouse cursor moving

This is **not** a system freeze, your mouse was still responding.

As further proved by your comment:

> when the system froze, I tried to login to the shell using through the command ALT + F1, but instead of shell, login "screen" appeared after some seconds, through which I was able to log into my user profile entering my password

---

Such problems are usually of software (desktop environment) or hardware (graphics card). My bet is the DE.

---

You can restart the DE via SSH from other machine, or (depending on what is more convenient) use the console, restart GNOME, get going again.

---

Opinion-based side note: You can try the new Ubuntu Cinnamon, [link](https://ubuntucinnamon.org/). I bet it will not "*freeze*".

Comment: Is this problem common while using Ubuntu with GNOME or any other DE?

Comment: I tried different DEs before (namely KDE, XFCE, and GNOME) installed 'side-by-side', but it ended up mixing their components with each other. E.g. If I logged in on the XFCE, I was seeing packages of KDE.
On searching for answers to use different DEs without interfering with each other, it turned out that you need to create different user profiles for each DE.

Is there a better way to do it? i.e. installing different DEs without causing them to interfere with each other

Comment: And after installing a DE, one cannot simply uninstall it completely without breaking anything else (dependencies) in the system. It becomes a mess!

Comment: Right. Best way in the long run is choosing a full-fledged distro which comes with DE preinstalled, try Linux Mint Cinnamon, or the Ubuntu Cinnamon, whatever makes you happy.